# How can I run a scala command line in databricks?

Tags: azure-databricks

In databricks, I wish to run the following scala command

```
scala [-cp scalatest-<version>.jar:...] org.scalatest.tools.Runner [arguments]
```

Can this be run within a scala notebook, or as a job?

I have tried various ways of running this command from within a notebook without success. I'm not sure if its possible or if I need to structure the sytax in such a way for it to work.

scalatest_2.12__3.0.8.jar is included within the databricks runtime

Comment: Could you please provide the error which you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A databricks job can be defined which runs a scalatest project:

specify:
Main class: org.scalatest.tools.Runner

Dependent libraries: (eg a jar containing the scalatest project)

Parameters: ["-R","dbfs:/ourProject.jar","-o","-f","/dbfs/ourLog.txt","-s","uk.xxx.xxx.xxx.Main","-DmaxConnections=100"]